# Optimal way to create dark version of website in PHP

Tags: php, css

I have a PHP MySQL based website with a pure black background and just white text and content. I want to have a switch button that will invert all the image files and the HTML itself to have a brighter version but I don't want the change to be visible in the URL. Here are the CSS changes that I want to make after the click:

```
.member-icon, .smaller_icons, .main_logo, .footer_lower_part img, .first_smalls {
filter: invert(0);
}
html, img, .partnerimg, .b_l_contacts, .logo_holder, .dark_mode{
    filter:invert(1);
}
```

and the button itself:

```
<div class="dark_mode">
<img src="/pics/body/dark_mode/dark_mode.svg" alt="dark mode switcher">
</div>
```

I'm looking for the optimal way to have a value toggled that will make PHP load the extra CSS throughout the whole session and not show up in the URL.

[image: Dark Version]

[image: Light Version]

The switch (the moon icon on the bottom right) is in the body.php file that is consistent in all the other pages.
The website is artfabers.com if you want to take a look.

Comment: You need JavaScript for that

Comment: Without javascript you can make the moon a link with a parameter like `?dark=1` and when you have that parameter in URL, you echo your CSS. But I think JS would be more elegant and you wouldn't have to reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to make it visible in the URL and you do not want to use JavaScript, you have some other options:

- Use sessions
- Use cookies
- Store setting in the database, if the user is logged in (it doesnt seem so in you screenshot)

I would go with the session solution.

When clicking the button, you should send a call to php that the user want to switch background color.

If you use a get request (simply just `<a href="?bg=black">moon</a>`) you would have to redirect the user right after you have set the session to remove it from the URL.

If you use a POST form, it will not be visible in the URL, but you would have the annoying "Are you sure you want to resend form-data"-confirmation dialog when refreshing/going back in the browser etc. So I would use a redirect for that as well.

*Example*

The HTML:

```
<div class="dark_mode">
    <a href="settings.php?bg=dark">
        <img src="/pics/body/dark_mode/dark_mode.svg" alt="dark mode switcher">
    </a>
</div>
```

settings.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['bg'])) {
    $_SESSION["bg"] = $_GET['bg'];
}

header('Location: index.php');
```

Now you can access the current background color in body.php by calling $_SESSION['bg']

The above is untested, but should work and at least give you an idea how to solve it.

I want to mention though, that this is a very old-fashioned way of doing such things.
I would look into a JavaScript solution if I were you which would not require a page refresh.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I don't know much javascript If there's an easy way to do it with javascript and have it consistent throughout the session and without cookies that would be great

Comment: You have to keep the state somehow. Either by saving the state in the database, sessions, cookies, localStorage or passing it through an URL parameter. So you have to pick one. Here is a blog article to do it with javascript and saving it in local storage https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/dark-light-switch-css-javascript , but I would suggest you to implement the solution from above now, because I think it fits your current level, and then look into javascript a bit more in the future. There is almost always a better way, but I also find it important to do it with the tools you master.